# Reportable Sp_Who2

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my issues with sp_who2 is that you need to be in the console to run it as it recalls spid twice and most reporting tools throw this as an error.

My question is, would using the code below to reformat `sp_who2` be a more reliable approach than taking the definition for `sp_who` and removing the

> --Handy extra for right-scrolling users.

as it is described!

```
Create Proc [Reports].[UspResults_sp_who2]
As
Begin 
    Declare @Results Table
        (
            [SPID] Int
        , [Status] Varchar(Max)
        , [LOGIN] Varchar(Max)
        , [HostName] Varchar(Max)
        , [BlkBy] Varchar(Max)
        , [DBName] Varchar(Max)
        , [Command] Varchar(Max)
        , [CPUTime] Int
        , [DiskIO] Int
        , [LastBatch] Varchar(Max)
        , [ProgramName] Varchar(Max)
        , [SPID_1] Int
        , [REQUESTID] Int
        );

    Insert  Into @Results
            ( [SPID]
            , [Status]
            , [LOGIN]
            , [HostName]
            , [BlkBy]
            , [DBName]
            , [Command]
            , [CPUTime]
            , [DiskIO]
            , [LastBatch]
            , [ProgramName]
            , [SPID_1]
            , [REQUESTID]
            )
            Exec [sys].[sp_who2];

    --Only show SPID once, show blocked processes first, followed by CPU time and DISK IO hoggers
    Select  [SPID]
            , [Status]
            , [LOGIN]
            , [HostName]
            , [BlkBy]
            , [DBName]
            , [Command]
            , [CPUTime]
            , [DiskIO]
            , [LastBatch]
            , [ProgramName]
            , [REQUESTID]
    From    @Results
    Order By [BlkBy] Asc
            , [CPUTime] Desc
            , [DiskIO] Desc
            , [SPID] Asc;
End;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another option if you are on SQL Server 2012+.

You can use [`WITH RESULT SETS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) and alias the problematic duplicate column name (as BonusSpid below).

```
EXEC sys.sp_who2
WITH RESULT SETS
(
  (
      SPID INT NOT NULL,
      Status VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      Login SYSNAME NULL,
      HostName SYSNAME NULL,
      BlkBy SYSNAME NULL,
      DBName SYSNAME NULL,
      Command VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      CPUTime INT NULL,
      DiskIO INT NULL,
      LastBatch VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      ProgramName VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      BonusSpid INT  NOT NULL,         /*Now unique name*/
      RequestId INT NULL 
  )
);
```

This option has the same disadvantage as the table variable solution that it is vulnerable to breakage if the definition of `sp_who2` changes and columns are added and or removed from it (RequestId was added in 2005 I believe).

This is an undocumented stored procedure so potentially it could alter definition or be removed from the product at any time without warning.

On the other hand if you copy and paste the code yourself into a new module you will lose the possibility of automatically benefiting from any improvements/ bug fixes if the code is altered.

You should consider using [`sp_whoisactive`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/tags/sp_5F00_whoisactive/default.aspx) rather than any of the above however as it is much more actively developed and has a wealth of additional features.